# 12.04 Dual Boot w/ Windows 8 hangs at purple screen. Black screen in recovery. Please help!

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I recently installed 12.04 alongside Windows 8 on my ASUS laptop. I ran boot repair after the install in order for grub to show up and let me have a choice between windows and Ubuntu. However, upon choosing Ubuntu the system hangs at a purple screen and the recovery mode goes to black. I have integrated graphics (Intel HD 4000). Please let me know what information I need to provide/how to get that information. I've been through multiple posts on this issue but the solutions didn’t seem applicable since I don’t have access to a terminal. Any help would be very appreciated.

Attempts at fixing this: Editing the kernel by removing quiet splash, replacing with nomodeset, no splash, and all other similar suggestions. RESULT: No effect. No dump of information on the screen. Additionally, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> would not work. Had to <kbd>F10</kbd> out of the editor.

Should I reinstall? Installing it through my flash drive (the current installation) alongside Windows 8 was very sketchy. I had to make three partitions one for the ext4 file system, one for swap, and one for a reserved boot space.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I have looked at the above possible link. It addresses Nvidia and AMD but i am running integrated Intel graphics. Replacing "quiet splash" with "no splash" and "nomodeset" still leaves me at a purple screen if in fact I edited things correctly.

Comment: actually you only have to "delete quiet splash" not "replace quite splash"

Comment: no dice. It seems like whatever I enter into the kernel has no effect on the purple screen. I'm stumpted as to how to proceed.

Comment: Edit your question and add every attempt to fix this. Also, if you delete the `quiet splash` there should be a dump of information scrolling in the screen, can you take a picture and add it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Some newer Intel need this instead of nomodeset.

Asus i3 with Intel graphics:

acpi_osi=Linux
video=1280x1024-24@75

or whatever native resolution is

Comment: Tried the above line with 1366x768 (the max res on my laptop). Still got to a purple screen.